# In Rails, how can I display a date such as 2009-12-01 as Monday, December 1st, 2009

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a birthday field in my database which has a date value as `yyyy-mm-dd`. I want to display it as being more human friendly. So `2011-11-15` should show up as `Tuesday, November 15th, 2011`.
The very strange thing is that when i do a `@user.birthday` in rails console, the value does show up in the format I want. But not on the web.

I am not sure what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@user.birthday.strftime "%A, %B %d,%Y"
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason it does not show up in the right format is that Rails in the view does call a `to_s` if necessary.

You should the [Internationalization and Localization of Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#the-public-i18n-api) to do that.

So in your example, `I18n.l @user.birthday` should do the trick. You should check what the default date format for your locale is, this is located at `config/locales/.yml. You may add your format by following the explanation in ["How to store custom translations"](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#how-to-store-your-custom-translations). So by adding

```
en:
  date:
    formats:
      default: "%A, %B %d,%Y"
```

this format will be used where ever you call `I18n.l` on a date.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `<model>.created_at.to_date.to_s(:long)`